# Deleting all the clone node of a table row in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

```
function newRow(t) {

    var parent = t.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;

    var row = t.parentNode.parentNode.cloneNode(true);

    row.firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild.setAttribute('value', 'sumit');

    parent.appendChild(row);

}

function removeRow(t) {

    var y = t.parentNode.parentNode;
    y.parentNode.removeChild(y);

}
```

the above code is working fine but i want to delete all the clones at once  which are created by above code on a onchange event of a select box

Comment: Please, don't traverse the DOM like `foo.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode`. Either give elements `id` hooks, fetch by `tagName`, or traverse recursively.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a class name to the cloned elements which would allow you to search for them and delete them later:

```
var row = t.parentNode.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
row.className += ' clonedrow';
...

// Remove all the cloned rows
var clonedRows = document.querySelectorAll('.clonedrow');
for (var i = 0; i < clonedRows.length; i++) {
  clonedRows[i].parentNode.removeChild(clonedRows[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the cloned rows have been added to the DOM, they look (to JavaScript) just like the original rows.

Since you're just appending cloned rows to the table body, what I would do is as follows:

- Outside the functions, as soon as the document loads, use `.childNodes.length` to get the number of rows in your table and store it globally in, say, `lastpos`.
- When you need to delete the clones, start at `.childNodes[lastpos]` and remove nodes until the table has `lastpos` rows again.